# Order of device initialization at Linux boot

Tags: linux, boot, systemd

I'm working on embedded system with screen connected over HDMI, but screen initialization takes longer than is comfortable for user. When I have ploted boot sequence by systemd-analyze tool, I have found, that HDMI device is initialized after 13-14 second, like almost last device initialized.

So my question is, what determines order of devices initialization and how to prioritize HDMI? I need to display some static image as soon as possible, otherwise user starts panic, because device seems to be dead.

Comment: Trying to get the display available sooner involves too many hardware and software dependencies. The common solution is (a) configure a bootloader (e.g. U-Boot) to display a splash image, and/or (b) configure the Linux kernel  to display a splash image. Both U-Boot and the Linux kernel offer this capability in their build configuration.

Comment: I have U-Boot configured to display splash image, But booting Linux turns screen black after 2-3 seconds. Current situation is: User turn on device -> 3 seconds black screen -> 3 seconds U-Boot splash screen image -> 15 seconds black screen -> 1 seconds image pushed to /dev/fb0 -> 5 seconds black screen (due to final application boot) -> final application screen. I have tried various methods to display splash screen, but all of them waits for screen init, none of then can speed up this process.